# Run-time error 1004 for Vlookup

Tags: excel, vlookup

I'm getting a run-time error on the following code and not sure what's causing it. The code is meant to run a vlookup for cells, but it returns a blank instead of a "0" if the lookup does not exist.

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(LEN(VLOOKUP(RC[-3], Schedule!C[-3]:C[-2], 2,FALSE))=0,"",VLOOKUP(RC[-3], Schedule!C[-3]:C[-2], 2,FALSE))"
Range("G2").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("G2:G600"), Type:=xlFillDefault
Range("G2:G600").Select
```

I'm sure it's something minor, but it's driving me nuts and i can't force the program to continue regardless of the error

Comment: To simplify your formula, you can just wrap the entire thing in an `IFERROR` function so you don't have to write the formula twice. Much cleaner, and I think it might solve your problem. Try putting that exact formula in cell G2 and see if it works or not, without using VBA.

Answer (score 0):

Your double quotes are syntactically right for VBA but false for the resulting formula. The VBA string `"=IF(...,"",...)"` is resulting in `=IF(...,",...)` which is not correct syntax for an Excel formula.

Correct should be:

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(LEN(VLOOKUP(RC[-3], Schedule!C[-3]:C[-2], 2,FALSE))=0,"""",VLOOKUP(RC[-3], Schedule!C[-3]:C[-2], 2,FALSE))"
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I knew it was some sort of simple syntax.